# Disable updating a certain field after initial creation of record

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to set-up a mongoDB collection so that even if a person gained access to the DB they wouldn't be able to change the value of a specific field?

Here is my schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
 firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 passwordDigest: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
 isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true
 }
});
```

I want to lock in the value of isAdmin. Is there any way to hard-wire this through the database set-up?

Comment: MongoDB itself "does **not** have a schema". So ask yourself, If the database does not know ( or care ) what properties exist in a given document, then how could you set "permissions" on such a thing? Kind of self conclusive

Comment: What you *can** do is something like [Implement Field Level Redaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/), where this is more of something you implement in your application code rather than the database level. But as noted on the duplicate, there are issue tickets but given the schemaless nature I would not expect these to resolve any time soon